# Why does OpenXML read rows twice

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I count rows in two worksheets like this:

```
foreach (WorksheetPart worksheetPart in workbookPart.WorksheetParts)
{
    OpenXmlPartReader reader = new OpenXmlPartReader(worksheetPart);
    if (count == 0)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Row))
            {
                count_first++;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (count == 1)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Row))
            {
                count_second++;
            }
        }
    }
    count++;
}
```

For both worksheets in `count_first` and `count_second` I get twice as much as there are rows with data. Why is that and what does it actually mean? Does it mean that `OpenXML` parses each list twice?

**EDIT**

Well, I found a solution. To get it right away, I guess, you should keep this sacred knowledge in some secret place. So, here it is:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Row))
    {
        do
        {
            count_first++;
        }   while (reader.ReadNextSibling());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have an *answer*, please post it *as* an answer, not as an edit to your *question*. Also, after a time delay, you can mark it as the accepted answer. Answering your own questions is a perfectly acceptable behaviour here on SO. But we know that questions have been satisfactorily dealt with when they have an accepted answer (at the moment, your question still appears to be unanswered)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are getting twice the count is due to the way the `OpenXmlReader` reads each element. The reader treats the open and close nodes as independant items which can be differentiated by checking the [`IsStartElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.openxmlreader.isstartelement%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [`IsEndElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/documentformat.openxml.openxmlreader.isendelement%28v=office.14%29.aspx) properties.

To demonstrate this you can run something like this:

```
using (OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Row))
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", 
                                  reader.ElementType,
                                  reader.IsStartElement,
                                  reader.IsEndElement);
            } while (reader.Read());

            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        }
    }
}
```

Which will produce output along the lines of the following* for a sheet with two rows and two columns (I've highlighted the Rows for readibility):

> **Row True False**
>   Cell True False
>   CellValue True False
>   CellValue False True
>   Cell False True
>   Cell True False
>   CellValue True False
>   CellValue False True
>   Cell False True
>   **Row False True**
>   **Row True False**
>   Cell True False
>   CellValue True False
>   CellValue False True
>   Cell False True
>   Cell True False
>   CellValue True False
>   CellValue False True
>   Cell False True
>   **Row False True**

There are 2 ways that you can solve this depending on how you want to read the document. The first way (as you point out in your answer) is to move to the next sibling by calling `ReadNextSibling` - this essentially "jumps" the end element (and any children of the `Row`). Changing the above example to use `ReadNextSibling` in the `do` loop:

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", 
                       reader.ElementType,
                       reader.IsStartElement,
                       reader.IsEndElement);
} while (reader.ReadNextSibling());
```

You'll get output* of:

> Row True False
>   Row True False

The second way would be to just count the start elements (or indeed the end elements; just not both):

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Row) && reader.IsStartElement)
    {
        count_first++;
    }
}
```

Which one you choose depends on whether you wish to read the `Cell` values and *how* you'd like to read them (SAX or DOM).

* In reality each row is prefixed with the namespace of "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet." which I've removed for readibility.

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Row))
    {
        do
        {
            count_first++;
        }   while (reader.ReadNextSibling());
    }
}
```