# OpenXmlReader is not extracting all the cell contents from an excel .xlsx sheet VB Net

Tags: excel, vb.net, xml-parsing, openxml-sdk

OpenXmlReader is not extracting all the cell contents from an excel .xlsx sheet

I have some code which was originally taken from SO and converted to VB Net: [Using OpenXmlReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555507/using-openxmlreader)

My code loops through the first 14 rows of the worksheet without any problem but then will not find any cells further down.

reader.ElementType appears to find *rows* past 14 (If reader.ElementType Is GetType(Row) Then), but no more *cells* (GetType(Cell))

The last cell extracted is L14, but the excel file has cell contents up to L29.

**Source Code:**

```
Public Shared Function fncParseXLSXorXLSM(strFileName As String, sbTxtFromFile As StringBuilder) As StringBuilder

    sbTxtFromFile.Length = 0
    Dim intFirst As Integer = 1

    Try

        Using spreadsheetDocument__1 As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(strFileName, False)
            Dim workbookPart As WorkbookPart = spreadsheetDocument__1.WorkbookPart

            Dim sharedStringItemsArray As SharedStringItem() = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements(Of SharedStringItem)().ToArray()

            Dim sheets As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets = spreadsheetDocument__1.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets

            ' For each sheet, display the sheet information.
            For Each sheet As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement In sheets
                For Each attr As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlAttribute In sheet.GetAttributes()
                    Debug.Print("{0}: {1}", attr.LocalName, attr.Value)
                    If attr.LocalName = "state" And attr.Value = "hidden" Then
                        Debug.Print("{0}: {1}", attr.LocalName, attr.Value)
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            For Each worksheetPart As WorksheetPart In workbookPart.WorksheetParts

                Dim reader As OpenXmlReader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart)

                While reader.Read()

                    If reader.ElementType Is GetType(Row) Then
                        reader.ReadFirstChild()
                        Do
                            If reader.ElementType Is GetType(Cell) Then
                                Dim c As Cell = DirectCast(reader.LoadCurrentElement(), Cell)
                                Debug.Print(c.CellReference.ToString)

                                '********************************************************************
                                ' Placed here to identify the last row openXmlReader seems to get to
                                '********************************************************************
                                If c.CellReference.ToString = "L14" Then
                                    Stop
                                End If
                                '********************************************************************
                                ' Placed here to identify the last row openXmlReader seems to get to
                                '********************************************************************

                                If c.DataType IsNot Nothing AndAlso c.DataType.Value.ToString = "SharedString" Then
                                    'Dim ssi As SharedStringItem = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements(Of SharedStringItem)().ElementAt(Integer.Parse(c.CellValue.InnerText))
                                    Dim ssi As SharedStringItem = sharedStringItemsArray(Integer.Parse(c.CellValue.InnerText))

                                    If Not ssi.Text Is Nothing Then
                                        If Not ssi.Text.Text Is Nothing Then
                                            If intFirst = 1 Then
                                                sbTxtFromFile.Append(ssi.Text.Text)
                                                intFirst = 2
                                            Else
                                                sbTxtFromFile.Append(Environment.NewLine & ssi.Text.Text)
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    Else
                                        If Not ssi.InnerText Is Nothing Then

                                            If ssi.InnerText Like "*Total of 25 CP TR Units*" Then
                                                Stop
                                            End If

                                            If intFirst = 1 Then
                                                sbTxtFromFile.Append(ssi.InnerText)
                                                intFirst = 2
                                            Else
                                                sbTxtFromFile.Append(Environment.NewLine & ssi.InnerText)
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    If Not c.CellValue Is Nothing Then
                                        If intFirst = 1 Then
                                            sbTxtFromFile.Append(c.CellValue.InnerText)
                                            intFirst = 2
                                        Else
                                            sbTxtFromFile.Append(Environment.NewLine & c.CellValue.InnerText)
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        Loop While reader.ReadNextSibling()
                    End If
                    If sbTxtFromFile.Length > 0 Then
                        sbTxtFromFile.Append(Environment.NewLine)
                    End If
                End While
            Next
        End Using

        Return sbTxtFromFile

    Catch ex As Exception
        If ex.Message Like "The process cannot access the file '*" Then 'File in use
            sbTxtFromFile.Append("|11readonly11|")
        End If
        'MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Function
```

Here is the link to the .xlsx file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7UpFja70T8_X1p5dzdPX3o3UzQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not quite the answer I wanted (I believe I should still be able to return all cells using my original code), I have resolved my issue by removing the outer 'IF' statement which was finding the row, reading the first child and looping through all the siblings. 
The code now just finds elements that are cells and returns the values.

```
'Previous Code

While reader.Read()
    If reader.ElementType Is GetType(Row) Then
        reader.ReadFirstChild()
            Do
                If reader.ElementType Is GetType(Cell) Then
                    'Code Here
                End If
           Loop While reader.ReadNextSibling()
    End If
End While


'New Code   
While reader.Read()
    'If reader.ElementType Is GetType(Row) Then
    'reader.ReadFirstChild()
    'Do
    If reader.ElementType Is GetType(Cell) Then
        Do
            'Code Here
        Loop While reader.ReadNextSibling()
    End If
    'Loop While reader.ReadNextSibling()
    'End If
End While
```