# OpenXmlReader gets certain values in Excel cells wrong

Tags: c#, excel, cell, openxml

I'm using OpenXmlReader in a C# program, to read excel files. For my purposes (comparison of values), I need the exact cell values, without any modifications.

**However, OpenXmlReader interprets certain Excel cell value types (concretely, percentages, dates and times) in an irritating way, that I seemingly have no control over.**

Imagine this to be an Excel row (what I expect to be read):

```
BNK | BNK_DC | GROUP | GROUP | 8 | 0,12% | 0,14% | 0,15% | 0,17% | 0,18%
```

This is how the row appears on my debug console:

```
BNK | BNK_DC | GROUP | GROUP | 8 | 1.1561E-3 | 1.3554245994127801E-3 | 1.5389154190192354E-3 | 1.7010741265663695E-3 |1.8389123386463213E-3
```

Basically, the strings are being read correctly, the simple integer as well. However, the percentages are transformed into something I can't grasp or work with.

Something similar happens when I try to read dates or times.

The excel file row:

```
04.04.2018 | Adam Smith | 09:30 | 17:30 | 8,0 | Apr | Q2
```

What OpenXmlReader returns:

```
43194 | Adam Smith | 0.39583333333333331 | 0.72916666666666663 | 8 | Apr | Q2
```

As you see, the date and times have been transformed into something I don't understand.

I guess this may have to do with a certain way percentages, times and dates are being stored internally by Excel. If so, how do I transform these values back into a readable format?

This is the exact code I use to read Excel files with the OpenXmlReader class and display them onto my Debug console:

```
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet; 
    using System.Diagnostics; 

    public void ExcelReader(SpreadsheetDocument document)
    {
        var wbp = document.WorkbookPart;
        var wsp = wbp.WorksheetParts.First();

        OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(wsp);
        string text;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Row))
            {
                reader.ReadFirstChild();

                do
                {
                    if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Cell))
                    {
                        Cell c = (Cell)reader.LoadCurrentElement();
                        string cellValue;
                        if (c.DataType != null && c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
                        {
                            SharedStringItem ssi = wbp.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(int.Parse(c.CellValue.InnerText));
                            cellValue = ssi.Text.Text;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cellValue = c.CellValue?.InnerText;
                        }

                        Debug.Write($"{cellValue} | ");
                    }
                } while (reader.ReadNextSibling());
                Debug.Write("\n");
            }
        }

        document.Close();
    }
```

I took this code mostly from the first answer to the following thread:
[Using OpenXmlReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555507/using-openxmlreader)

**So, how do I get my actual percentages, dates, times from Excel, instead of these strange values?**
Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your do {} I would suggest to add         switch (theCell.DataType.Value)
        {    
            // Now you have a type, parse to this type (float.Parse, etc)
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Date**

The Date is stored in Days after the 01.01.1900

**Time**

The time is stored in 24h * the number so 24h*0.395833=9,5 => 09:30

**Percentage**

If u use `Convert.ToSingle(number)` `1.1561E-3` will become `0.0011561` which is 0.115%